# Extract an object's property value and use that as the dictionary key

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

I have input in this format:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Product one",
    "productId":"12345",
    "itemCode":"7037"
  },
  {
    "name":"Product two",
    "productId":"67890",
    "itemCode":"9101"
  },
  {
    "name":"Product three",
    "productId":"111213",
    "itemCode":"7047"
  }
]
```

For each object in the array, I want to take the value of the name property, and use it as the property name for the resulting object. The output I want is:

```
{
  "Product one": {
    "productId":"12345",
    "itemCode":"7037"
  },
  "Product two": {
    "productId":"67890",
    "itemCode":"9101"
  },
  "Product three": {
    "productId":"111213",
    "itemCode":"7047"
  }
}
```

Here's the closest I was able to get to it:

```
.[] |  { (.name) : { productId: .productId, vendorId: .vendorId } }
```

Here's the output that produces:

```
{
  "Product one": {
    "productId": "12345",
    "vendorId": null
  }
}
{
  "Product two": {
    "productId": "67890",
    "vendorId": null
  }
}
{
  "Product three": {
    "productId": "111213",
    "vendorId": null
  }
}
```

That creates double-nested products, and doesn't include spaces between them.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach here would be to create the three objects in the array and then "add" them:

```
 map( { (.name): del(.name) } ) | add
```

Output:

```
{
  "Product one": {
    "productId": "12345",
    "itemCode": "7037"
  },
  "Product two": {
    "productId": "67890",
    "itemCode": "9101"
  },
  "Product three": {
    "productId": "111213",
    "itemCode": "7047"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to convert an array into an object is arguably via the [`from_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) function, like so:

```
map({key: .name, value: del(.name)}) | from_entries
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **reduce**:

```
reduce .[] as $e (
     {}
   ; .[$e.name] = ($e | del(.name))
)
```